# Outputting values not equal to certain values in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions

I would like to output variables not equal to certain values but it returns an error of

```
Failed to prepare SQL: SELECT * FROM `tblsuunit` WHERE `unitid` != :qp0
```

There are two models the first model where am getting the array of ids

```
public function actionSunits($id){
    $unitslocation = new Unitslocation();
    $id2 = Unitslocation::find()->where(['officelocationid'=>$id])->all();
      foreach( $id2 as $ids){
      print_r($ids['unitid']."<br>");
      }
    }
```

This outputs the ids as

```
8
9
11
12
13
14
16
```

I would then like to take the id and compare another model(units model) and get the id values not similar to the above and output then

So i have added

```
 $idall = Units::find()->where(['!=', 'unitid', $ids])->all();
```

So the whole controller action becomes

```
public function actionSunits($id){
    $unitslocation = new Unitslocation();
    $id2 = Unitslocation::find()->where(['officelocationid'=>$id])->all(); 


   foreach( $id2 as $ids){
         $idall = Units::find()->where(['!=', 'unitid', $ids])->all();

     }
     var_dump($idall);

}
```

This is the units model table:

[image]

If it were working it should return 7 and 10

What could be wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your code and simply use a `not in` condition, e.g. :

```
// $uls will be an array of Unitslocation objects
$uls = Unitslocation::find()->where(['officelocationid'=>$id])->all(); 

// $uids will contain the unitids
$uids = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($uls, 'unitid');

// then simply use a not in condition
$units = Units::find()->where(['not in', 'unitid', $uids])->all();

$idall = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($units, 'unitid');
```

Read more about [`ActiveQuery::where()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail) and [`ArrayHelper::getColumn()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#getColumn()-detail).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$idall = Units::find()->where(['not in','unitid',$ids])->all();
```

**Info**: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md

> operand 1 should be a column or DB expression. Operand 2 can be either
>   an array or a Query object.